# What are some fun activities hams participate in?

Tags: fox-hunt

Yes, Amateur radio is a hobby. The general impression however is that it is a geeky/nerdy/kooky (I forget which carries a negative connotation!) hobby; either the ham sits at a transceiver, or is doing something with an oscilloscope, soldering iron, some meters & books at the other table.

The only *fun* activity that comes to mind which makes the hobby relatively visible is a fox-hunt. But ... I'm still a beginner.

What are some *fun* activities that help increase the visibility of the hobby?

Comment: too broad as written, ask specific questions about fox hunting, field day, and stuff

Comment: @Dan I'm hoping to find out about 'stuff' with the question (+:

Comment: sure, but it's too broad for this format because there's no single answer that's right. That's the sort of thing that would be a good topic on a forum or your local club, but not a q&a site

Answer (score 1):

For me, the ability to interact in real time with a person on the other side of the planet and get to know them a bit has been **lots** of fun.

Comment: Agreed; but say that to a layman, and he'll probably come back with the remark he can do it with a lot less effort using a telephone/computer. In most cases by the time it's explained he'll probably be asleep.

Answer (score 1):

I take part in four main activities as an activator:

- Worked All Britain
- World Wide Flora & Fauna
- Castles and Stately Homes on the Air (affiliated to the World Castles Award)
- Summits on the Air (although this one has become rarer)

For all three activities, I've ended up in parts of the UK that I would probably not have visited, and seen places I wouldn't otherwise have done.  And once I get my Advanced Licence, this will extend to other countries.

I've met some very nice people, and been offered cups of coffee in homes across the country.  I have a list of overseas visits to make.

The only real downer is that I have failed (so far) to persuade my partner to get her licence... but my eldest daughter is very interested, so maybe I'll have an activation partner soon enough :)

I appreciate that many operators cannot get out and about, and are shack-bound - but for those who can, I commend portable and mobile activity... it brings a very different dimension to the hobby.